# how to save and load this deeplabv3+ model ..... I have to deploy it on raspberry pi

Tags: pytorch, deeplab

Cannot save and load model
"https://www.kaggle.com/code/utkarshsaxenadn/flood-area-segmentation-deeplabv3/notebook"
..help?

tried,
torch.save(DeepLabV3, path)
model=torch.load(path)
but not working..again I have to train the model

Comment: Your post is missing a lot of useful information such as the complete error message, the code that you tried to execute and potentially many other details. A good first step would be to [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. Additional suggests for questions that are likely to get useful answers can be found in [ask].